# how to deploy an apache cordova app on iOS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

I don't own a MAC, so I rented a MAC on macincloud, now, when I try to open the VS project in VS for MAC it won't open. After a short reading I found out that I have to connect VS for MAC to my project but I haven't figure it out and that is why I've come to you guys.

Does anyone knows a site that have step by step tutorial or article on how to do it?

or how to deploy an iOS app made in Visual Studio Taco?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but the method I prefer to create the iOS app from Visual Studio is to not use it directly, rather copy the project's www folder to the Mac and build there manually. This process is [explained in detail on this page](https://www.andreszsogon.com/build-cordova-ios-app-from-visual-studio-for-windows/).